# How to create country list using array in javascript? i have total 10 or more select country box in page

Tags: javascript, html, dropdown

How to create country list using array using js? i have total 10 or more select country box in page. i want to create using class name.

```js
var country_arr = new Array("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa" /*, ... */ );

function country() {
  var x = "<option disabled>Select Country</option>";
  
  for (var i = 0; i < country_arr.length; i++) {
    var node = country_arr[i];
    x += "<option value='" + country_arr[i] + "'> " + country_arr[i] + " </option>"
  }

  var countryElement = document.getElementsByClassName('country');
  countryElement.innerHTML = x;
  document.getElementsByClassName("country").innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<div style='text-align:center;'>
  <select class="country" name="country"></select>
  <select class="country" name="country"></select>
  <select class="country" name="country"></select>
</div>

<script>
  country();
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do querySelectorAll, getElementsByClassName and other getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will cycle through the array, create an option and then appends it to all selects with `.country`. This solution uses jquery.

```js
var country_arr = new Array("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa");

country_arr.forEach( function(obj) {
  var temp_country = new Option(obj, obj);
  $(temp_country).html(obj);
  $("select.country").append(temp_country);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="country" name ="country"></select>
<select class="country" name ="country"></select>
<select class="country" name ="country"></select> </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for jquery script. But how to set option value.

Answer (score 1):

You nee to iterate over the `HTMLCollection` elements you get with `document.getElementsByClassName("country")`:

```js
var country_arr = new Array("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa" /*, ... */ );

function country() {
  var x = "<option disabled>Select Country</option>";
  
  for (var i = 0; i < country_arr.length; i++) {
    var node = country_arr[i];
    x += "<option value='" + country_arr[i] + "'> " + country_arr[i] + " </option>"
  }
  
  let list = document.getElementsByClassName("country");
  for (let item of list) {
    item.innerHTML = x;
  }

}

country();
```

```html
<div style='text-align:center;'>
  <select class="country" name="country"></select>
  <select class="country" name="country"></select>
  <select class="country" name="country"></select>
</div>
```